# Styling Specific BarButtonItems for iOS application

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 5 appearance API to style all the baritembuttons to a specific style as shown below:

```
 id barButtonAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];
      [barButtonAppearance setBackgroundImage:[theme imageForBarButtonNormal] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Everything works fine except now I have a confirm barbuttonitem which I want to style differently. I try to style it in the controller using the following code:

```
self.confirmBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

But it still take the UIAppearance style. How can I style a UIBarButtonItem differently?

Comment: Here is an excellent article that'll help you:  http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/